# kaminari and page from elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

Is it possible to have Kaminari helper and use already paginated data:

**1.** I query elasticsearch and make all pagination there get 10 records from 2 page.

**2.** Then I get model instances

**3.** instances should be shown on UI with page buttons e.g. 1,2,3 next>

I don't know how to do it with Kaminary helper it always complain:

**undefined method `current_page for #<ActiveRecord::Relation**

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using the gem `Tire` to integrate with elasticsearch on rails.

Kaminari by default works on Activerecord result set / collection or directly on Tire results object. For instance if you have a model `Post` integrated with `Tire` you can say,

```
results = Post.search do
    query do
        #..
    end
    size 10
    from (page_num - 1) * 10
end

results.next_page #returns true if next page is present
results.total #return total number of search results available
```

And in your view you can directly use

```
<%= paginate results %>
```

The key is to maintain or hold a reference to the Activerecord result set or Tire results. The paginate methods are not defined on the ActiveRecord model instances.

If you're trying to get the results from elastic search, then based on ids fetched load the records from database and then send back an array you cannot use `paginate` you will have to use the kaminari method for arrays [Paginating Arrays with Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object).

You can instead directly tell `tire` to load the active record objects:

```
Post.search 'term', :load => true
```